# How do I fill a list with with tuples using a for-loop in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, search, graph-theory, dijkstra

I just finished implementing a working Python code for the Dijkstra-Pathfinding algorithm. I am applying this algorithm to a graph with edges, which I have written as a list of tuples:

```
graph = Graph([
        ("a", "b", 2),("a", "c", 5),
        ("a", "d", 2),("b", "c", 3),
        ("b", "e", 1),("c", "e", 1),
        ("c", "h", 1),("c", "f", 1),
        ("c", "d", 3),("d", "g", 2),
        ("e", "i", 7),("f", "h", 3),
        ("f", "g", 2),("h", "i", 1)])
```

I don't want to leave it like that and rather fill the graph using a for-loop, but this is exactly where I fail.

I have tried writing

```
graph.append(("i", "j", "4"))
```

And several other variants using the append function but it just keeps giving me errors.
I am aware that this isn't a for-loop, I am simply trying to add one edge for now.

This is how I defined my add_edge function:

```
Edge = namedtuple('Edge', 'start, end, cost')
def add_edge(start, end, cost):
    return Edge(start, end, cost)
```

Comment: What is `Graph` here? You need to add the class definition for it

Comment: To append a tuple to the list graph you would have: `graph.append(("i", "j", 4))` (also change the last item to a number rather than string for weight).

Comment: You're wasting peoples time if you don't provide information on the `Graph` class you are using.

Answer (score 0):

In this line the parenthesis are serving as a container for multiple string arguments.

```
graph.append("i", "j", "4")
```

You need to add a layer of nested parenthesis to indicate that the argument is a single tuple.

```
graph.append(("i", "j", "4"))
```

Comment: I have already tried that, it gives me " 'Graph' object has no attribute 'append' "

Comment: @Saturday7 You could populate a list before using it to initialize the `Graph` object.